# VNC reverse ssh tunnel behind public ip of VPS

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vnc, vps

I have a VPS, and I am trying to expose my local Mac's VNC through the VPS to the internet.

```
MacOS's VNC server at vnc://192.168.1.100/ <--SSH--> VPS <--Internet--> VNC Viewer
```

So I did :

```
ssh -R 6999:192.168.1.1:5900 root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

```
ssh -R 6999:0.0.0.0:5900 root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

```
ssh -R 6999:127.0.0.1:5900 root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

And connected to the public ip address of the VPS in VNC viewer `(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6999)` and it doesn't work, I tried some debugging and I can my test working on the VPS using 127.0.0.1 but it just doesn't work behind the public IP! I don't know why.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thank you yes it does :) you can post that as an answer I needed to do :
-R "*:6999:localhost:5900" with "GatewayPorts yes" at /etc/ssh/sshd_config